# Searching for strings in files along with using os.walk

Tags: python

I have written a Python Script to find out lines containing a particular script from each of the files within a directory. It works fine if i make this script run in the directory having those files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def searchthis(location, searchterm):
    for fname in os.listdir(location):
        fullpath = os.path.join(location, fname)
        for line in file(fullpath):
            if searchterm in line:
                print line



searchthis(os.getcwd(), "mystring")
```

Is there any way I could do this with `os.walk` and search for recursively in each of the files present in all the directories as well as subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

def searchthis(location, searchterm):
   for dir_path, dirs, file_names in os.walk(location):
      for file_name in file_names:
         fullpath = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
         for line in file(fullpath):
            if searchterm in line:
                print line

searchthis(os.getcwd(), "mystring")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple iterator like this:

```
def all_files(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(dir)):
        for f in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, f)
```

for example:

```
 for path in all_files(os.getcwd()):
     with open(path) as f:
         for n, line in enumerate(f, 1):
             if term in line:
                 print path, n
```

Comment: Worked great as well. Thanks a lot.